# Firing off additional addClass with roundabout jQuery carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-roundabout

I don't quite know how to explain this one, but i'll try my best.

I've been following this tutorial [here](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/how-to-build-a-custom-carousel-with-jquery-and-roundabout/) to build an image based jquery carousel using the roundabout platform.

The carousel itself works, as I went through the tutorial but I'm trying to add an additional action when one of the control span tags is clicked.. to do the removeClass / addClass for a div underneath showing detailed information about the currently active carousel item.

JQUERY CODE:

```
(function($) {

var $descriptions = $('#carousel-descriptions').children('li'),
$controls = $('#carousel-controls').find('span'),
$carousel = $('#carousel')
    .roundabout({childSelector:"img", minOpacity:0 })
    .on('focus', 'img', function() {
        var slideNum = $carousel.roundabout("getChildInFocus");

        $descriptions.add($controls).removeClass('current');
        $($descriptions.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
        $($controls.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
    });

$controls.on('click dblclick', function() {
var slideNum = -1,
    i = 0, len = $controls.length;

for (; i<len; i++) {
    if (this === $controls.get(i)) {
        slideNum = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (slideNum >= 0) {
    $controls.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $carousel.roundabout('animateToChild', slideNum);
}
});

}(jQuery));
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="carousel">
<img src="images/weapons/handgun.png" alt="Handgun" class="slide" />
<img src="images/weapons/shotgun.png" alt="Shotgun" class="slide" />
<img src="images/weapons/assault-rifle.png" alt="Assault Rifle" class="slide" />
<img src="images/weapons/sniper-rifle.png" alt="Sniper Rifle" class="slide" />
</div>
<div id="carousel-controls">
  <h3>Click on a weapon type:</h3>
<span class="control current" id="handgun">Handgun</span>
<span class="control" id="shotgun">Shotgun</span>
<span class="control" id="assault-rifle">Assault Rifle</span>
<span class="control" id="sniper-rifle">Sniper Rifle</span>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail current" id="handgun">
  <p>Ballistic details for handguns</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail" id="shotgun">
  <p>Ballistic details for shotguns</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail" id="assault-rifle">
  <p>Ballistic details for assault rifles</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail" id="sniper-rifle">
  <p>Ballistic details for sniper rifles</p>
</div>
```

Is there anything really simple I can add to the existing jQuery code to link up the id of the span controls to the id of the div i want to be shown?

I have created this on JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3WhB/) but it doesn't seem to be working the same as on my website. I think i've attachd everything needed. Anyway, if anyone wants to add to it, please do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID so I'd structure your HTML like this:

```
<div id="carousel-controls">
    <h3>Click on a weapon type:</h3>
    <span class="control current" id="handgun">Handgun</span>
    <span class="control" id="shotgun">Shotgun</span>
    <span class="control" id="assault-rifle">Assault Rifle</span>
    <span class="control" id="sniper-rifle">Sniper Rifle</span>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail handgun-info">
    <p>Ballistic details for handguns</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail shotgun-info">
    <p>Ballistic details for shotguns</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail assault-rifle-info">
    <p>Ballistic details for assault rifles</p>
</div>
<div class="ballistic-detail sniper-rifle-info">
    <p>Ballistic details for sniper rifles</p>
</div>
```

Then use this javascript:

```
var ballisticDetail = $('.ballistic-detail'),
    control = $('#carousel-controls .control');

control.on('click', function(){

    if( $(this).is('.current') ) return;

    control.addClass('current').not(this).removeClass('current');
    ballisticDetail.removeClass('current')
                   .filter('.'+ this.id +'-info')
                   .addClass('current');

});
```

The first two lines are caching the jQuery objects as we'll be using them every time the `click` event fires.

The first line of code in the `click` event function prevents anything happening if the `span` is already active.

The `current` class is the added to the clicked `span` and the corresponding `div`. It adds the `current` class to all the `span`s then uses the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function to filter out all the elements that are *not* the one that was clicked and remove the `current` class from them.

The second part removes the `current` class from all the detail boxes then uses [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to return the detail box that has a class with the clicked `span`'s ID plus `-info`.

The CSS I used was:

```
.ballistic-detail{
    display: none;
}
.ballistic-detail.current{
    display: block;
}
span.control.current{
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.control{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/EFH7K/

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to add something like this to your click event handler:

```
$controls.on('click dblclick', function() {

    ....

    $('.ballistic-detail').hide(400, function(){
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
});
```

That should work. It is a little hard to tell though without a working test.